# How to filter to drop grouped rows? filter(any())

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

This is what I want to do, but it does not work.

Within each pair (each pair consists of two rows of data) I want to completely drop the pairs in which one or both members did not receive a response. If one member of the pair has a 0 in the response column, I want both rows corresponding to that pair to be dropped.

I am using tidyverse to clean my data.

```
BothResponses <- FinalData %>%
  group_by(Pair) %>%
  filter(-any(Response == 0))
```

Comment: Change the `-` to `!`  .  Negate changes TRUE to FALSE and viceversa or instead of doing negation.  use `all(Response != 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
DiffResponses <- FinalData %>%
  group_by(`Audit Pair`) %>%
  filter(any(Response == 0) == FALSE)
```

I tried this and it worked!